# How can I transfer my application to IPad

Tags: ios, development

I am thinking about development small applications for IPad and I'm just wondering how can I transfer my application to my IPad?

I don't have a plans to sell or to distribute my software among the other users.  All what I want is to use my app by myself.  How can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a non jailbroken iPad you NEED to enroll iOS Dev Program, which cost 99$/Year and then use Xcode.

Cf : https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/

There may be other frameworks that work without jailbreaking and/or Xcode.